# Where to find the file location of an SSL certificate? (Windows)

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to setup self-signed certificates on multiple servers inside our Windows domain.
I tried a few different ways before finding [this excellent guide](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) to setting up a root CA using OpenSSL.

However, now I cannot find the location of the existing (bad) SSL certificate for my development machine (localhost) to try and replace it!

[image: Localhost Certificate information in Chrome]

I've looked in both MMCs for Local Computer (`certlm.msc`) and Current User (`certmgr.msc`) - sorted by name & by date (which stands out), searched every folder... nothing.

How do I find **where** this older certificate is, so I can delete it?

Comment: Which Web server are you using?

Comment: Windows Server / Nginx on the servers, Windows 10 / Chrome on the clients.

Comment: You might be able to use `netsh http show sslcert`, find the certificate in question (by the hash), and then see if the "Certificate Store Name" points you in a helpful direction.

Comment: When adding the Certificate snap-in to MMC, there are three options: My User Account, Service Account, and Computer Account. It sounds like you've checked User and Computer, so maybe the certificate in question is under a Service Account store -- perhaps for the service account that Nginx uses.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like Nginx looks for the certificate files (typically a .pem and a .key) in a file location instead of in the Windows certificate store. Your `nginx.conf` file should tell you where it is looking.

Comment: Not meaning to necromance here but I think I ran into the similar issue.  You need to use the utilities `certlm` to "export" the certificate to a file.